# Uncaught TypeError: this.props.forecast.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react, have seen some similar issues but haven't found why this is happening. I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: this.state.data.map is not a function". Here is the code. Please help find what the problem is.

```
  import React from "react";
    
    class Forecast extends React.Component {
        render() {
            const forecastItems = this.props.forecast.map((f) => {
                const url = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${f.wather[0].img}@2x.png`;
                let ampm = 'AM';
                let hour = new Date(f.dt * 1000).getHours();
    
                if (hour > 12) {
                    hour = hour - 12;
                    ampm = 'PM';
                }
                return (
                    <div className="forecast-item">
                        <p className="forecast-item__hour">{hour}:00 {ampm}</p>
                        <p className="forecast-item__temp">{f.temp}</p>
                        <img src={url} alt={f.weather[0].description}/>
                        <p className="forecast-item__description">{f.wather[0].main}</p>
    
                    </div>
                );
            });
            return (
                <div className="forecast">
                {forecastItems}
        </div>);
        }
    }
    
    export default Forecast;
```

Here is the parent companet, where I use my code to get the weather api, it seems to be doing everything right.

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import SearchMenu from "./Components/search-menu/search-menu";
import CurrentWeather from "./Components/current-weather/current-weather";
import Forecast from "./Components/forecast-weather/forecast-weather";

import {getCurrentWather, getForecast} from './Components/api/weather.api';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            location: "",
            temp: "",
            feelsLike: "",
            description: "",
            img: "",
            hourlyForecast: ""
        };
    }

    onInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            location: e.target.value
        });
    }

    async onFormSubmit() {
      const weatherRes = await getCurrentWather(this.state.location);
      const lat = weatherRes.data.coord.lat;
      const lon = weatherRes.data.coord.lon;
      const forecastRes = await getForecast (lat,lon);

        this.setState({
            temp: weatherRes.data.main.temp,
            feelsLike: weatherRes.data.main.feels_like,
            description: weatherRes.data.weather[0].main,
            img: weatherRes.data.weather[0].img,
            hourlyForecast: forecastRes.data.hourly
                });
            }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <SearchMenu
                        location={this.state.location}
                        inputChange={(e) => this.onInputChange(e)}
                        formSubmitted={() => this.onFormSubmit()}
                        />
                    <CurrentWeather
                        currentTemperature={this.state.temp}
                        feelsLike={this.state.feelsLike}
                        description={this.state.description}
                        img={this.state.img}
                    />
                    <Forecast forecast={this.state.hourlyForecast} />
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }


export default App;
```

[image]

Comment: Share more login from your code. for example where you are using this component? and what props you are sending to this component?

Comment: I am using this to get the weather api

Comment: Share segments that related to this component. because I think you did not passed forcast as an array.

Comment: Added parent component

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor initialize your state like below

```
...
this.state = {
            location: "",
            temp: "",
            feelsLike: "",
            description: "",
            img: "",
            hourlyForecast: []
        };
```

What is different is that hourlyForecast is now an empty array and not an empty string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped, but now another error "forecast-weather.js: 9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Answer (score 0):

You set state for `hourlyForecast` in parent component with string initial value and is not array of data. You should set state like below:

```
this.state = {
 ...
 hourlyForecast: []
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped, but now another error "forecast-weather.js: 9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Comment: Still you get error? @DenisPrudnikov

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be something like this below,
I guess you are passing hourlyForecast as a string which array map function don't understand and throws type error.

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import SearchMenu from "./Components/search-menu/search-menu";
import CurrentWeather from "./Components/current-weather/current-weather";
import Forecast from "./Components/forecast-weather/forecast-weather";

import {getCurrentWather, getForecast} from './Components/api/weather.api';

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            location: "",
            temp: "",
            feelsLike: "",
            description: "",
            img: "",
            hourlyForecast: []
        };
    }

    onInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            location: e.target.value
        });
    }

    async onFormSubmit() {
      const weatherRes = await getCurrentWather(this.state.location);
      const lat = weatherRes.data.coord.lat;
      const lon = weatherRes.data.coord.lon;
      const forecastRes = await getForecast (lat,lon);

        this.setState({
            temp: weatherRes.data.main.temp,
            feelsLike: weatherRes.data.main.feels_like,
            description: weatherRes.data.weather[0].main,
            img: weatherRes.data.weather[0].img,
            hourlyForecast: Array.isArray(forecastRes.data.hourly) ? forecastRes.data.hourly : [forecastRes.data.hourly]
                });
            }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                    <SearchMenu
                        location={this.state.location}
                        inputChange={(e) => this.onInputChange(e)}
                        formSubmitted={() => this.onFormSubmit()}
                        />
                    <CurrentWeather
                        currentTemperature={this.state.temp}
                        feelsLike={this.state.feelsLike}
                        description={this.state.description}
                        img={this.state.img}
                    />
                    <Forecast forecast={this.state.hourlyForecast} />
                </header>
            </div>
        );
    }
    }


export default App;
```

Comment: Here we should be sure forecast as a prop is an array and the issue is not related to component state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped, but now another error "forecast-weather.js: 9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')"

Comment: Can you log a sample output of forecastRes.data.hourly here we can determine what could be the issue

Comment: Can you use something like this just below the rest call to see what is the output for the same

const forecastRes = await getForecast (lat,lon);
console.log(forecastRes.data.hourly);

Comment: @Ankit , I added a photo of the logs

Comment: @DenisPrudnikov the image is fine can you please copy a sample response (can you click on the right arrow before number 48 and copy a sample response of the same. we are very close to it. I doubt the issue is with (forecastRes.data.hourly ) property which might not be an array so we have to format it to be in the array form.

Comment: @Ankit Added a photo of the array, everything seems to be fine with it

Comment: @DenisPrudnikov I doubt the property wather doesnt exist and we are trying to read it from the object and trying to index 0 property of the wather which doesn't exist
Can you add a undefined check condition for the wather property so that it works or is it weather property that might be a typo as well (can you elaborate any of the object shown in the screen shot and copy the sample output i.e lets say 11th object elaborate it and paste the sampel response so that we can get the root cause) 
const url = `http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${f.wather[0].img}@2x.png`;

Comment: @Ankit When requesting 11 objects, an error is also issued. ncaught TypeError: Cannot read undefined properties (read '11')